# Outdoor, in ground, smart lighting solution

Tags: smart-device, smart-home

I am looking to replace some cheap solar LED lamp post lights along my driveway, with an in ground lighting solution. I have a few requirements though:

- Must be hardwired to power, not solar powered. I am in the US, so it need to be compatible with the standard power grid here.
- Must use something that is easily replaceable, should a light stop working.
- Must be compatible with Google Assistant and/or [Home Assistant](https://www.home-assistant.io/) so that I can control it from an appropriate device
- I'd like it to be multi-colored, so that I can adjust the color and brightness of the light based on time of year
- I'd like it to be in ground, not small lamp posts.

This is going to go along the driveway and I anticipate this will take 10-15 lights (based entirely off my solar light test). The driveway is approximately 50 feet in length.

My budget for the hardware is less than $500. Installation will be done by myself. This budget eliminates things like the Hue product line, because their outdoor lights are over $100 per light.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for does not yet exist **as a product**. You should expect to pay much more than that if you want a professional system that works with smarthome devices.

[This system](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B07ZKB5921/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_U_tPHfEbNDJCXQH) is very close to what you are asking for but it is not smart home compatible.

However, that doesn't mean you can't put something together yourself. You could use a [waterproof mount](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B005GOGDCE/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_U_ckHfEb4M6H7HX) with [budget smart bulbs](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B07KYQ3W46/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_U_q7GfEbZ7Q9S04), or use [colored outdoor lights](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B07RTXHJLR/ref=emc_b_5_i) paired with a [smart power switch](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B07JB5TQSG/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_U_dJHfEbPPDNDAN). (Recommendations for each inline.)